# Как перенести значение каждого отдельного div'a на определенный div

Tags: javascript, html

Имеются несколько дивов с классами. Мне нужно чтоб при каждой нажатии на определенный див, значение этого дива скопировалась на определенный див. Пока что у меня получается скопировать значение только перво-стоящего дива.

Код:

```js
function func(){
  var a = document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML;
  var b = document.querySelector('.number').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('.name1').innerHTML= a;
  document.querySelector('.number1').innerHTML= b;
  
  alert(a);
}
```

```css
/* Fonts from Google Fonts - more at https://fonts.google.com */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700');

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.diva, .divc {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.divb {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="divc" onclick=func()>
      <div class="name">Alex</div>
      <div class="number">38</div>
    </div>
    <div class="diva" onclick=func()>
      <div class="name">Joe</div>
      <div class="number">12</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="divb">
      <div class="name1">Name</div>
      <div class="number1">Age</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function func(e) {
  document.querySelector('.name1').innerHTML = e.children[0].innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('.number1').innerHTML = e.children[1].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.diva,
.divc {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.divb {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="divc" onclick=func(this)>
  <div class="name">Alex</div>
  <div class="number">38</div>
</div>
<div class="diva" onclick=func(this)>
  <div class="name">Joe</div>
  <div class="number">12</div>
</div>

<div class="divb">
  <div class="name1">Name</div>
  <div class="number1">Age</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(){
document.querySelector('.name1').innerHTML = this.children[0].innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.number1').innerHTML = this.children[1].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: выдает ошибку "Cannot read property 'children' of undefined". Hе могли бы вы написать полный код или ссылку

Answer (score 0):

для начала почему Ваш код не работает должным образом.
при использовании метод `document.querySelector('.name')` ищет в DOM дереве **первый попавшийся** элемент, что в Вашем случае есть `div` c классом *name*. то есть, Вы каждый раз обращаетесь к одному и тому же элементу (с данными Alex 38).

а вот моя версия решения этой задачи

```
function func(e){
  const name = e.currentTarget.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
  const num = e.currentTarget.lastElementChild.innerHTML;

  document.querySelector('.name1').innerHTML= a;
  document.querySelector('.number1').innerHTML= b;

  alert(name, num);
}
```